# How do I type hint a return type of one function based init if init is overloaded

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I have a class that accepts either ints or floats in it's init but all must be int or float so i am using `typing.overload` to achieve that and I want to be able to type hint the return of a function based on the given values.

```
class Vector3:
    @overload
    def __init__(self, x: int, y: int, z: int) -> None:
        ...
    @overload
    def __init__(self, x: float, y: float, z: float) -> None:
        ...

    def __init__(self, x, y, z) -> None:
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
        self._z = z

    # This function
    def __key(self) -> tuple[int | float, int | float, int | float]:
        return (self._x, self._y, self._z)
```

Also how would I type hint the values of x, y, and z? I plan to use `@property` to obfuscate the _x, _y, _z values and don't know how I'd type hint them either.

```
@property
def x(self) -> int | float:
    return self._x
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't overload `__init__` at all. Make `Vector3` generic instead, using a constrained type variable.

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T', int, float)

class Vector3(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, x: T, y: T, z: T) -> None:
        self._x: T = x
        self._y: T = y
        self._z: T = z

    def __key(self) -> tuple[T, T, T]:
        return (self._x, self._y, self._z)

    @property
    def x(self) -> T:
        return self._x

    # etc
```

Then

```
reveal_type(Vector3(1, 2, 3))  # Vector3[int]
reveal_type(Vector3(1., 2., 3.)) # Vector3[float]
reveal_type(Vector3(1, 2, 3.)) # Vector3[float], via promotion of int values to floats
reveal_type(Vector3('1', '2', '3'))  # type error, T cannot be bound to str
```

Note that `int` is considered a subtype of `float` in this context.

Comment: Perfect! I thought Generics would come into play here!

Comment: What if I used `T = TypeVar('T', int | float)` instead of `T = TypeVar('T', int, float)`

Comment: That's an error, attempting to create a type variable with just one constraint. You might be thinking of `T = TypeVar('T', bound=int|float)`. In the specific case of `int | float` (because `int` is treated like a subtype of `float`), it would probably have the same effect, but in general it's not what you want. (Consider `int | str` instead; `Vector3(1, '2', 3)` would produce a `Vector3[int|str]` value, rather than failing to create either a `Vector[int]` or a `Vector[str]`, as desired.)